# CKRecordID is not identical to 'AnyObject'

Tags: ios, swift

Going through one of my old swift problems and I fixed most of the issues, but this one.

```
var ids : [[CKRecordID]] = []
for i in items {
    ids.append(i.recordID)
}
```

Getting the following error: `'CKRecordID' is not identical to 'AnyObject'` when I try to append the ids. Any idea why this is occurring?

Also tried casing it as an Array and it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

`ids` is `[[CKRecordID]]`, whereas the code sample appears to treat it as if it were `[CKRecordID]` (that is: an array of record ids, rather than an array where each member is itself an array of record ids).

Comment: Even if I treat it as the latter I get the same error.